# passing additional arguments to django's login & template

Tags: django, templates, authentication, arguments

My application uses Django's login view from django.contrib.auth.views.login, with a custom template I made.

I'd like to pass my template an additional argument which will change the login page in a few ways. Actually, I'm trying to show a different login page based on the URL.

How can I pass additional arguments to the login's view & to my custom template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source shows there is only one place that would influence the template context.

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm): # here
```

So your only option is to hitch a ride on `AuthenticationForm` or write your own login view (which, by the way, is *very* simple if you look at the code).

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

AuthenticationForm.my_extra_data = 'foobar'

(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', \ 
     {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html', \
      'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm }),
```

Template

```
{{ form.my_extra_data }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended wrapping the whole login function with my own code.

Answer (score 5):

On Django 1.3 the login view accepts a new `extra_context` argument in the form of a dictionary.

*django/contrib/auth/views.py*

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
      redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      current_app=None, extra_context=None):
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to [Roberto Rosario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181907/roberto-rosario)'s answer, you can pass a dictionary of arguments to `extra_context` inside your `urls.py`

*yourProject/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, {
        'template_name': 'your-template-dir/login.html',
        'extra_context': {
            'additional_arg1': val1,
            'additional_arg2': val2,
            ...
        },
    }, name="login"),
    ...
]
```

Which will then be available in your template.

*yourProject/your-template-dir/login.html*

```
{% extends "your-template-dir/base.html" %}

<div>
    <p>The value of 'additional_arg1' is {{ additional_arg1 }}.</p>
    <p>The value of 'additional_arg2' is {{ additional_arg2 }}.</p>
</div>
```

Here's [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login).

Answer (score 0):

I was having an heck of time passing extra context variables from my custom login view-function to the template. They were all printing out as the empty string, despite following advice from a number of people a lot smarter than me.

Turns out my `urls.py` entry was still pointing to the [built in login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login), not my custom one.

Please don't let this happen to you.

> *When you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.* -- [Mr. Spock](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0001439/quotes)