# How to pass variables to login page in django 1?

Tags: django, django-templates

I overrided django admin login page and would like to pass some variables to the login page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: let me make it clear that I personally think you should write your own login view if you want to influence the context, namely because it's so simple (you can copy and paste the  ~20 lines to your own view).

Since what I like to do on stackoverflow is find a way around anyways, here's a hacky alternative:

---

If you want to use the built in admin page the only method I see is to attach properties to `AuthenticationForm`.

Here's `django.contrib.auth.views.login`:

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm):
    ....
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The only place we can 'hitch a ride' into the login template while positively not affecting anything else is through `AuthenticationForm`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

AuthenticationForm.foobar = 'Hello'
...
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', \
      {'authentication_form':AuthenticationForm),

# template
{{ form.foobar }}
```

Another alternative is to use a [context processor,](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) which injects variables into **every** view that uses `RequestContext`. Use this if your variable has some use in other templates as well.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to use extra_context parameter (Django 1.3 and newer).

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
...
return login(request, template_name, extra_context={
    'template_variable':value
})
```

See these similar questions and answers:

- [Adding extra_context in Django logout built-in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757062/adding-extra-context-in-django-logout-built-in-view)
- [passing additional arguments to django's login & template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109814/passing-additional-arguments-to-djangos-login-template)

And the original feature ticket:

- [Ticket #5298: The extra_context keyword argument...](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5298)

Comment: Great answer. You can also pass this directly in the `url.conf` as well instead of using a custom view: `urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'extra_context':{'title': 'My Page | Log In'}}, name='login'), ...`

Answer (score 2):

For clarity (I commented on Akseli's answer) another solution is to pass the extra template variables directly along from `url.conf` via the `extra_context` key:

```
# url.conf -- this example from older django versions refer to docs
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(
        r'^accounts/login/$', 
        login, 
        {
            'template_name': 'login.html', 
            'extra_context': {
                # Your extra variables here as key value pairs.
                'title': 'My Page | Log In'
            }
        }, 
        name='login'
    ),
... # other patterns
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Akseli said, use extra_context, but pass the extra context as part of the context:

```
def login(...):
    ...

    some_var = some_var.objects.all()
    extra_context = {'some_var': some_var,}

    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)

    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context, current_app=current_app)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add your custom attribute to the `request` which is available in the template i.e.

```
request.my_params = {
    'my_param1':'my_param1',
    'my_param2':'my_param2',
}
```