# Add Extra_Context to App View (urls.py)

Tags: django, url, view

I want to add an additional dictionary to userena's profile detail view, but I cant figure out how to add `extra_context` to the view in my urls.py. The error is `VariableDoesNotExist`:

```
thing_list = {
    'queryset' : Thing.objects.all(),
    'template_object_name' : 'thing',
}

from userena import views as userena_views

url(r'^(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$',
   userena_views.profile_detail,
   {'extra_context':{'thing_list': thing_list}},
   name='userena_profile_detail'),
```

I am basing this on the answer to this SO question:

[Adding extra_context in Django logout built-in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757062/adding-extra-context-in-django-logout-built-in-view)

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
thing_list = {
    'queryset' : Thing.objects.all(),
    'template_object_name' : 'thing',
    'extra_context': {'swamp_things': Thing.objects.filter(type='swamp')},
}

url(r'^(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$',
   userena_views.profile_detail,
   thing_list,
   name='userena_profile_detail'),
```

*As for your latest comment (how to get the request into the queryset filtering).*

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import list_detail

def requestuserswampers(request):
    qs = Thing.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return list_detail.object_list(
                request,
                queryset = Thing.objects.all(),
                template_object_name = 'thing',
                extra_context = {'swamp_things': qs},
    )
```

And in your `urls.py`

```
from views import requestuserswampers

url(r'^(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$',
       requestuserswampers,
       name='userena_profile_detail'),
```

Reading the documentation for [Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/generic-views/#generic-views) is very good and it will teach you a lot as how the Generic Views actually work and what you can do with them!

Comment: Oh ok. How can I include the queryset as the extra_context though??

Comment: Ok thanks! You answered my question, but just wondering now how to get the request ContextProcessor into this so that I can say `'extra_context': {'swamp_things': Thing.objects.filter(user=request.user)},` I would appreciate any ideas to help me get over this last hurdle, but thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yeah, I'll add it to the answer just for kicks ;)

Comment: Thanks @limelights, I appreciate your help. But for some reason now there is a syntaxerror corresponding on line `'template_object_name' : 'thing',` Sorry to bother you but I feel so close to the solution..

Comment: Yeah, it's because a `:` snuck in there instead of a `=`. :) Sorry!

Comment: Oh right thanks. Any idea why this may return `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33161/discussion-between-limelights-and-nick-b)