# Django: Add Queryset to App View with Request

Tags: django, view, filtering, django-queryset

This is a continuation of my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555895/add-extra-context-to-app-view-urls-py) about how to include additional queryset (with request) in an app (Userena) view. If I do what @limelights suggested, this is what my code looks like:

view:

```
from django.views.generic import list_detail

def requestuserswampers(request):
     qs = Thing.objects.filter(user=request.user)
     return list_detail.object_list(
                 request,
                 queryset = Thing.objects.all(),
                 template_object_name = 'thing',
                 extra_context = {'swamp_things': qs},
     )
```

url:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>(?!signout|signup|signin)[\.\w-]+)/$',
       requestuserswampers,
       name='userena_profile_detail'),
```

This generates a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error: `Template does not exist at myapp/swamp_things.html`.

If I try to include the template name and location using `template_name = 'userena/profile_detail.html'`, on the other hand, the right template is rendered, but some of the context is now missing, like the user information that is normally rendered in the default userena "profile_detail" template..

How do I add an extra queryset to the Userena profile detail view which allows for request so that I can filter objects based on the logged in user? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Hey! If you're running into much problems with this approach I would recommend rewriting the view function as a proper function as I think it would be for the best! :) I'll help you out when I get home tomorrow though, if someone else hasnt already! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that it was accepted practice to re-write another app's view, figuring that it was antithetical to DRY principles. But since I had not discovered another method of achieving what I needed to do, and since it was endorsed by another senior user in the comments above, I went ahead and tried to re-write the Userena view. Just needed to add my queryset into the `extra_context`:

```
def profile_detail(request, username,
    template_name=userena_settings.USERENA_PROFILE_DETAIL_TEMPLATE,
    extra_context=None, **kwargs):

    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                         username__iexact=username)

    profile_model = get_profile_model()
    try:
        profile = user.get_profile()
    except profile_model.DoesNotExist:
        profile = profile_model.objects.create(user=user)

    if not profile.can_view_profile(request.user):
        return HttpResponseForbidden(_("You don't have permission to view this profile."))
    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['profile'] = user.get_profile()
    extra_context['hide_email'] = userena_settings.USERENA_HIDE_EMAIL

        #### Added the line below
    extra_context['swamp_things'] = Thing.objects.filter(user=user) 

    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```