# Django template tag on built-in login User.objects.all()

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using built-in login of django. How I can display all the first name of the registered user on its template using tags?

There's no function to add a context because it is built-in so
this is what I added to my **urls.py**, the kwargs thing what I read to other post.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login', kwargs={'all_user': User.objects.all()}),
```

my template at **registration/login.html** as default

```
{% for user in all_user %}
    <option>{{ user.first_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

When I am accessing now the login it returns an error:

> LoginView() received an invalid keyword 'all_user'. as_view only
>   accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.

Is there a way that I can put the context on built-in login?

Comment: May be you need [adding-extra-context-in-django-logout-built-in-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757062/adding-extra-context-in-django-logout-built-in-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'extra_context':{'all_user':User.objects.all()}}, name='login'),
```

use like this

Comment: this works thanks, I put the name='login' to the last, seems getting syntax error if is before the extra context.

Answer (score 0):

You must have get all user in views on django like

views.py

```
class GetUser():
      def get_context_data():
          all_user = ....(get data from api for model database)
          context = {(
             'all_user': all_user,
          )}
          return context
```

html will be

```
{% for user in all_user %}
   <option>{{ user.first_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```