# Custom LoginView django extra_context

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

I did a custom loginView and I can't reach the extra_context dictionary in my template. (authentification works fine)

my view file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .models import EsportUser

class LoginViewCustom(LoginView):
    #esport_user = EsportUser.objects.first()
    #extra_context = {'test42': esport_user}
    template_name = 'users/login_register.html'
    extra_context = {'test42': 'test'}
```

my template file (login_register.html):

```
<a href="#">{% trans "Account" %}  {{  test42 }}</a>
```

my urls file:

```
path('login/', views.LoginViewCustom.as_view(), name='login', ),
```

Thanks, Stéphane

Comment: it's certainly there, but what is `EsportUser`?

Comment: Why would you think the *class* EsportUser would have an `id` attribute?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it , EsportUser is a model  -> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.EsportUser'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too late to share a good answer:

Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212408/4683950) , basically you can pass your additional extract context the `as_view()` method when calling it in the url.

So in your `url.py` file, you can have something like this :

```
path('login/', views.LoginViewCustom.as_view(extra_context={'test42': 'test'}), name='login', )
```

Answer (score 0):

Bird up @Stéphane, welcome to StackOverflow.

I think your problem is that EsportUser is your model (a model being the template you use to create objects).

Once you create an object instance of EsportUser model, (i.e. create a user, by the looks of what you're doing), you want to [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) your database to retrieve objects that belong to that model, *then* pass that **object** (or some of the object attributes) to the template.

Assuming you have an object instance of EsportUser (i.e. created a user), you could try:

```
# here you query the first EsportUser object
esport_user = EsportUser.objects.first()

# here you pass that object into extra_context - not the model itself
extra_context = {'test42': esport_user}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer and you are totally right. I modified my code to explain you my real problem I can't even catch a simple string from my extra_context in my template. I think that the problem may come from the redirection that occurs after the user connection.